# Group records for data analysis in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, data-analysis

I have two tables connected with habtm relation (through a table).

```
Table1
id  : integer
name: string

Table2
id  : integer
name: string

Table3
id       : integer
table1_id: integer
table2_id: integer
```

I need to group Table1 records by simmilar records from Table2. Example:

```
userx = Table1.create()
user1.table2_ids = 3, 14, 15
user2.table2_ids = 3, 14, 15, 16
user3.table2_ids = 3, 14, 16
user4.table2_ids = 2, 5, 7
user5.table2_ids = 3, 5
```

Result of grouping that I want is something like

```
=> [ [ [1,2], [3, 14, 15] ], [ [2,3], [3,14, 16] ], [ [ 1, 2, 3, 5], [3] ]  ]
```

Where first array is an user ids second is table2_ids.
I there any possible SQL solution or I need to create some kind of algorithm ?

Updated:
Ok, I have a code that is working like I've said. Maybe someone who can help me will find it useful to understand my idea.

```
def self.compare
    hash = {}
    Table1.find_each do |table_record|
      Table1.find_each do |another_table_record|
        if table_record != another_table_record
          results = table_record.table2_ids & another_table_record.table2_ids
          hash["#{table_record.id}_#{another_table_record.id}"] = results if !results.empty?
        end
      end
    end
    #hash = hash.delete_if{|k,v| v.empty?}
    hash.sort_by{|k,v| v.count}.to_h
  end
```

But I can bet that you can imagine how long does it takes to show me an output. For my 500 Table1 records it's something near 1-2 minutes. If I will have more, time will be increased in progression, so I need some elegant solution or SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Table1.find_each do |table_record|
  Table1.find_each do |another_table_record|
    ...
```

Above codes have performance issue that you have to query database N*N times, which could be optimized down to one single query.

```
# Query table3, constructing the data useful to us
# { table1_id: [table2_ids], ... }
records = Table3.all.group_by { |t| t.table1_id }.map { |t1_id, t3_records|
    [t1_id, t3_records.map(&:table2_id)]
  }.to_h
```

Then you could do exactly the same thing to `records` to get the final result hash.

UPDATE:

@AKovtunov You miss understood me. My code is the first step. With `records`, which have `{t1_id: t2_ids}` hash, you could do sth like this:

```
hash = {}
records.each do |t1_id, t2_ids|
  records.each do |tt1_id, tt2_ids|
    if t1_id != tt1_id
      inter = t2_ids & tt2_ids
      hash["#{t1_id}_#{tt1_id}"] = inter if !inter.empty?
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It's not the same thing. 
Your code hashes everything like {t1_id: t3_records}
And mine shows similar records for 2 t1 ids.

Comment: @AKovtunov You miss understood me. My code is the first step. With `records`, which have `{t1_id: t2_ids}` hash, you could do sth like this:

    hash = {}
    records.each do |t1_id, t2_ids|
      records.each do |tt1_id, tt2_ids|
        if t1_id != tt1_id
          inter = t2_ids & tt2_ids
          hash["#{t1_id}_#{tt1_id}"] = inter if !inter.empty?
        end
      end
    end

Comment: Ah, I got you idea. Yep, with hash it will be alot faster.